# Is there is a way to use Blogger ?alt=Json feed in AMP-list

Tags: blogger, amp-list

i have seen the [amp-list](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list/?format=websites) using src="example.com/json". but is there is a way to use blogger json feed inside amp-list?

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="140" layout="fixed-height" 
src="https://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json">
<template type="amp-mustache">
-----
</template>
</amp-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to render the data from a Blogger feed by using the following template configuration  -

```html
<amp-list width="auto" height="140" layout="fixed-height" items="feed.entry" src="...?alt=json">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <div class="title">{{#title}}{{$t}}{{/title}}</div> <!-- Shows the title of the post -->
    <div class="content">{{#content}}{{{$t}}}{{/content}}</div> <!-- Shows santized content -->
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

Comment: hi @prayag-verma thank you for your support . i tried this in playground.amp.dev but it returns nothing .. can you please give me suggestion please see the screenshot (https://ibb.co/q9dvd9Q)

Comment: @nixsjob That issue is happening because of the CORS restriction. If you try to use that example code on your website (https://www.nixs.in) itself, then it will work without any problems.

Comment: thank you @prayag-verma its work perfectly... but i need also Url and Thumbnail.. can you please tell me the code to fetch url and thumbnail of the post it the blogger json

Comment: For the post's thumbnail, it would be possible to get it via `{{#media$thumbnail}} {{url}} {{/media$thumbnail}}` but for getting post URL, there is no easy way because the post URL is present in a nested object. You can use `{{#link}}{{href}}{{/link}}` but that will output around 5 URLs (the number of URLs depends on different things like if comments are enabled or not, etc ). If getting the URL is unavoidable, then you will have to use the [Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger) (Endpoint would be https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOGID/posts?key=YourAPIKey)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to use blogger JSON in amp list;
for that you need to mention `items='feed.entry'` to enter into sub divisions of JSON
then follow the mustache template guidelines to fetch the required fields.